# extending asp.net control in the website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, vs-web-site-project

when I extend an asp.net control and place the extended control class in, say, Applicaton_code 
(without specifying the namespace) how do i register the control to use it on a webpage?
what assembly name and namespace should be specified?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use :

```
<%@Register TagPrefix="local" Assembly="App_Code" Namespace="Controls" %>
```

Also, you **HAVE** to defines a namespace where to put your controls (from memory, when adding class to App_code, no namespace is generated by default).

```
namespace Controls {
    public class control1 : WebControl {
    }

}
```

and then , in the aspx file

```
<local:control1 runat="server", id="youreluckyitworks" />
```

Comment: it missed an "at" sign actually, thanks for your vigilance :)