# asp:RequiredFieldValidator does not validate hidden fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms, controls

It seems that ASP.NET validators do not validate hidden fields. I get messages like this:

> Control 'hiddenField' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'hiddenFieldValidator' cannot be validated.

I have an `<asp:HiddenField>` in my page which gets filled client side with some value. I need this to be present once on the server so I added a `RequiredFieldValidator` to it.

And it does not work!

As I see it, as a workaround, I can:

**1.** use a custom validator and not tie it to the hidden field, just call a method on `OnServerValidate`;

**2.** Use a `<asp:TextBox>` with a CSS style `display:none` and it should work.

But I want to make sure I am not missing something here. Is it possible or not to validate a hidden field in the same way as the other text fields? O maybe a third, more elegant option?

TIA!

Comment: use custom validator and write js to validate your hidden field...

Comment: @Miroprocessor: Validation is there to make sure that what you get from the client is valid data. I don't care if it is filled by a user or by JavaScript, I need to validate ALL data and make sure it wasn't tampered with. Required validator for the hidden is just one of them, I have others to check the value itself against a set of allowed values

Comment: Good one +1. But could you explain the case/scenario where Hidden field has to be validated.

Comment: Here's my scenario: I have a TextBox with a jQuery auto-complete linked to it. When the user selects an item I set a hidden field to the selected id (client-side). So now the hidden field is required, not the original text box.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as the exception message you're getting says, it seems `HiddenField` controls can't be targeted by the standard validation controls directly. I would go with the `CustomValidator` workaround.

Comment: +1 for providing (IMHO) the most maintainable and flexible solution.

Answer (score 38):

@Peter's answer got me thinking, what does `ControlPropertiesValid` actually check??

Looking at the [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controlpropertiesvalid.aspx) it looks for, among other things, the `ValidationPropertyAttribute`.. Hhmm, so if we just derive from `HiddenField` and decorate the new class with `ValidationPropertyAttribute` set to `Value` (for my purposes) then 'everything just works'.  And it does.

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Partner.UserControls {
    [ValidationProperty("Value")]
    public class HiddenField2 : HiddenField {
    } // nothing else required other than ValidationProperty
}
```

Usage - make sure you register the assembly containing the control:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyApp" Namespace="MyApp.Controls" TagPrefix="sw" %>
```

And in your Page/UserControl content:

```
<sw:HiddenField2 ID="hidSomeImportantID" runat="server" />
```

All validators will work with this.  The added benefit is that if you (like me) are using a custom validation function you can easily evaluate the `HiddenField2.Value` because it is contained in the `args.Value` field (on server side this is `ServerValidateEventArgs`).

Comment: +1 - Brilliant! Compared to the effort of tuning a custom validator to validate both client- and server-side a hidden field element, this approach is excellent.

Comment: Glad to be able to help :-)

Comment: My approach was a good start, but yours is a way better finish.  I'll be sure to take this route in the future, thanks for sharing.

Comment: This is a great idea. I'm surprised more people haven't needed to do this.

Comment: +1 for providing the fastest, fully-functional solution! You may be interested in the solution that I posted, as well, which may provide further opportunities for improvements to .NET validation over the long-run.

Comment: Fantastic answer, Saved me a headache and an asperin. nice one.

Comment: Excellent, and trivial to implement if you're already maintaining a library of server controls.  This really should be the accepted answer.  Custom validators can be a pain for those not familiar with them.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the workaround I came up with, because unfortunately I couldn't find any reliable way to validate using the RequiredFieldValidator OR the CustomValidator out of the box.  If you leave the ControlToValidate property empty it yells at you. All you have to do is create a custom control like the one below:

```
public class HiddenFieldValidator : RequiredFieldValidator
{
    protected override bool ControlPropertiesValid()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

By overriding the properties valid check so that it always returns true it no longer cares that you are using a HiddenField and it will pull the value out of it and verify without issue.

Comment: +1 asp.net validation makes me angry! Good work around though

Comment: Peter - I am afraid that this will not work, as the call to `GetControlValidationValue` will not return the actual value of the `HiddenField`, as it is missing the `ValidationProperty`, as noted in @Scotty.NET's post, which is why the override that you provided is needed, in the first place.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel - This code was something I tested and used on a real project. Did you test it and it didn't work for you?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel - I did some more testing and I'll say we are both right... Client side validation works with the code I posted, but server side validation does not.

Comment: That makes sense, actually, that it would work for client-side validation, only. To answer your question, I did not test it this time, as I just know from extensive work with .NET validators and the `GetControlValidationValue` method that the value returned will be null. I did not consider client-side validation, however.

Comment: As per the correctness, I would not say your solution is incorrect, but rather is just a partial solution ;) I would also suggest that a slightly more defensive method body be implemented, but I do like how you left it to be generic so that others could play, as needed ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is a response to the solution by Scotty.NET. I just don't have enough reputation to reply.

+1 to Scotty.NET!

For those of us who don't know enough about .NET and compiling and such, this may help simplify usage of his answer for someone else.

I wanted to make use of it in a website using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express:

1) I saved the derived HiddenField2 in /App_Code as HiddenField2.cs, with one change --> `namespace Controls`

2) Then, to register the control:

a) On the page, `<%@ Register Assembly="App_Code" Namespace="Controls" TagPrefix="local" %>`

b) In web.config, within system.web > pages > controls, `<add tagPrefix="local" namespace="Controls" assembly="App_Code" />`

3) And, finally, of course, refer to it as `<local:HiddenField2 ...>`.

It does make for funky code coloring. Probably fairly easy to improve the namespace to handle that. Works wonderfully for me in my local environment; guess I don't know it won't have problems on a live server.

Additional reference:
[extending asp.net control in the website project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424603/extending-asp-net-control-in-the-website-project)

Comment: Nice one, this is def worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @Anders' solution, with a `CustomValidator` approach, you can very easily grab the value of a standard `HiddenField` control by first finding the control, casting it, and then using its `UniqueID` to look its value up in the `Page.Request.Form[]`.

**Example 1: Improving the Compare Validator**

This example may be a bit more local to your implementation. The below is an improved version of the `CompareValidator.EvaluateIsValid()` method call, in order to add support for validating `HiddenField` controls. Note that this technique can be applied to any validator, instead of wrapping the `HiddenField` in a custom control, but that the `ControlPropertiesValid` method should also be overriden to recognize and return true in the presence of a `HiddenField`.

```
...

private new string GetControlValidationValue(string id)
{
    var control = this.NamingContainer.FindControl(id); 
    if (control != null)
    {
        if (control is HiddenField) 
        {
            return Page.Request.Form[((HiddenField)control).UniqueID];
        } 
        else 
        {
            return base.GetControlValidationValue(id);
        }
    }
}

protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
{   
    // removed 'base.' from the call to 'GetControlValidationValue'
    string controlValidationValue = GetControlValidationValue(base.ControlToValidate);
    if (controlValidationValue.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    bool flag = (base.Type == ValidationDataType.Date) && !this.DetermineRenderUplevel();
    if (flag && !base.IsInStandardDateFormat(controlValidationValue))
    {
        controlValidationValue = base.ConvertToShortDateString(controlValidationValue);
    }
    bool cultureInvariantRightText = false;
    string date = string.Empty;
    if (this.ControlToCompare.Length > 0)
    {
        //same as above
        date = GetControlValidationValue(this.ControlToCompare);
        if (flag && !base.IsInStandardDateFormat(date))
        {
            date = base.ConvertToShortDateString(date);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        date = this.ValueToCompare;
        cultureInvariantRightText = base.CultureInvariantValues;
    }
    return BaseCompareValidator.Compare(controlValidationValue, false, date, cultureInvariantRightText, this.Operator, base.Type);
}

...
```

**Example 2: Custom Dynamic Validator**

This example is a bit more complicated than the first one. I regularly use custom dynamic validators that are enabled or disabled based on the value of another control on the page (e.g., if that box is checked then this textbox is required; otherwise it does not need to be validated). One such validator is my `DynamicRequiredFieldValidator`, which inherits from the built-in `RequiredFieldValidator`. The dynamic validator has two custom attributes, `ControlThatEnables` and `ControlValueThatEnables`, that are used to decide whether or not the validator should be turned on. The below is a snippet from the method that determines whether or not the validator should be enabled, but note that, as above, this same technique can be applied to validating a `HiddenField` without the need to wrap it in a custom control.

```
...

var enablingControl = this.NamingContainer.FindControl(ControlThatEnables); 
if (enablingControl != null) 
{
    if (enablingControl is HiddenField)
    {
        var hfValue = Page.Request.Form[((HiddenField)enablingControl).UniqueID];
        isValidatorEnabled = hfValue == ControlValueThatEnables;
    }
}

...
```

**Final Thoughts**

The implementation decision is ultimately up to you, as the developer, but my preference is to wrap existing validators in custom controls, rather than to wrap things like `HiddenFields`, `TextBoxes`, `DropDownLists`, etc. in custom controls. I have two main reason for preferring this solution: (1) wrapping the validators take only a few minutes more than just adding the `ValidationProperty`, but provides significantly more flexibility and opportunity for further improvement of .NET validaton, e.g. one could point the `FindControl` calls to some custom method that searches for the desired control ID in the current `NamingContainer` (default) and then expands the search to the outer `Page` or the `NamingContainer`'s parent if the control was not found; (2) IMHO if one is trying to improve validation, it is cleaner to make improvements to validation, and, contrarily, if one is trying to improve a `WebControl`, it is cleaner to make improvements to the `WebControl`.

I completely respect @Scotty's solution, and will be the first to admit that if it is the only change to be made, then his solution will save you 5 minutes more than this one. IMHO however, @Anders' is likely to be a better choice, in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a `CustomValidator` client side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myMethod(source, args) {
    args.IsValid = document.getElementById("<%= myValue.ClientID %>").value != '';
}
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="myValue" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="myMethod" 
                     ErrorMessage="Value missing!" />
```