# comparevalidation for text box value and hidden field value

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAppSanctionLimit" runat="server" onblur="calcCustDebtEquity()">     </TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfAppReqeustAmt" runat="server" Value="0" />

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Proposed Limit is never greater than Request Limit" ControlToCompare="txtAppSanctionLimit"       ControlToValidate="txtRequestLimits" Operator="GreaterThan" 
       ValidationGroup="Report3" Display="none" ></asp:CompareValidator>

<asp:Button ID="btnLimtUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" ValidationGroup="Report3" 
                onclick="btnLimtUpdate_Click"/>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary3" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="Report3"  />
```

Above all has been used in my defalt.aspx page under Visual Studio 2010.
I want to show Validation Message if  txtAppSanctionLimit value is greater than hfAppReqeustAmt value. note that hfAppReqeustAmt value get from database with query.

how can I solve this problem.

Comment: do you want to show this on button's click event? if yes then you can simply use javascript or jquery.

Comment: Are you trying to solve this in the browser (on the client) or in the codebehind (on the server)?

Comment: may u can use range validator ...

Comment: I would not rely entirely on the client side to enforce any real business logic. Is there a reason you would not put this in the code behind?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The attribute for the target

```
ControlToCompare="txtAppSanctionLimit"
```

should probably be pointed at your hidden field.

```
ControlToCompare="hfAppReqeustAmt"
```

and the attribute for the ControlToValidate should be pointed to your user data entry field.

```
ControlToValidate="txtAppSanctionLimit"
```

as it is currently pointing to a control that is not shown in the example code.

EDIT: Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.controltocompare(v=vs.110).aspx) for the CompareValidator.ControlToCompare -

> If the control to compare is hidden or is inside a container (such as
>   a Panel control) that is not visible, the validator performs
>   server-side validation only. The validator client script supports only
>   visible controls.

Comment: See post by Nico Westerdale.  You cannot use a hidden field in validation unless you use a CustomValidator.

Comment: @dshapiro - I have no problem with removing this answer or altering it to point elsewhere if its not useful or is blatantly incorrect. Please review the included edit and comment with any recommendation for improvement.

Comment: That blurb from the MSDN sounds as if it should apply to HiddenFields, but it seems that there's a special case specific to HiddenFields which isn't mentioned in the article.  I ran into this today and .NET will throw a big ol' exception if you use an asp:HiddenField as either the target (ControlToValidate) or the reference (ControlToCompare).

Comment: @dshapiro - Which .net version are you using?  If I can repro I'll log a connect bug to at least get the documentation clarified and link here.

Comment: I encountered it with a project running under .net 4.5.1, but based on other findings (via Google), I suspect this runs further back.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is completely incorrect!

Simply put you can't use a CompareValidator with a HiddenField. You need to use a CustomValidator.

See: [asp:RequiredFieldValidator does not validate hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607984/asprequiredfieldvalidator-does-not-validate-hidden-fields)

Comment: This is not a RequiredFieldValidator.

Comment: I know, but logic still applies, if i remember correctly